# non recursive destructor for binary search tree by implementing stack

Tags: c++, stack, binary-search-tree

This code has a runtime error and I am having problems with determining what the problem is. stack class has a basic stack operations(pop push top) and is used to save the location of traversal.

```
parityBST::~parityBST()
{

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;

    }
    else 
    {
        //postOrder non recursive traversal for destructor
        stack* s1 = new stack();
        s1->push(root);

        binaryNode* nodePtr= root;
        while (!s1->isEmpty())
        {
            //RUNTIME ERROR HERE (after several iterations)
            if (nodePtr->left)
            {
                s1->push(nodePtr->left);
                nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
            } else if (nodePtr->right)
            {

                s1->push(nodePtr->right);
                nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
            } else 
            {

                delete nodePtr;
                s1->pop();
                nodePtr = s1->getTop();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `delete`ing nodePtr while in (nodePtr's parent)->left, but not changing it into null, so you walk into it again.

try to add this:

```
s1->pop();
binaryNode* parent = s1->getTop()
if (parent->left==nodePtr)
    parent->left = NULL;
else
    parent->right = NULL;
delete nodePtr;
nodePtr = parent;
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. I am not deleting nodePtr while in nodePtr's parent->right.  Could you please post a solution? Thanks.

Comment: `delete nodePtr;` happens only if nodePtr is a leaf, doesn't it? but you don't make its parent a leaf.

Comment: but doesn't deleting nodePtr essentially make the left or right automatically NULL?

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but I get another runtime error

Comment: @LeonardLie - no it does not `NULL`ify. your new runtime error is probably in the root - I did not include check for that.